# Paste text from selenium with java into readonly input

Tags: javascript, python, java, html, selenium-webdriver

I have input div that if you click on it some method add some attribute for prevent the user added text with keyboard and use the wheel of select!
In java selenium I can get element remove readonly attribute but if use sendKeys nothing happen, because Keyboard input is off(maybe by javascript function or by navigator lock),if right click and paste some content work, that good to know if reselect the input the readonly and all class back it from javascript so what can I do to paste text from clipboard without right click or use (clt+V or shift + insert) which is looked.

The div looks:

```
<ui-text-field _ngcontent-ehh-c219="" label="تاریخ انقضا" name="expirationDate" _nghost-ehh-c120="">
   <div _ngcontent-ehh-c120="" class="text-field is-invalid is-readonly">
      <form _ngcontent-ehh-c120="" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
         <!----><input _ngcontent-ehh-c120="" formcontrolname="field" class="field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" type="text"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><label _ngcontent-ehh-c120="">تاریخ انقضا</label>
      </form>
      <!---->
   </div>
</ui-text-field>
```

Straight and Forward speak is : How can paste text content into div without right click/action preform or keyboard with selenium in java.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `executeScript` method provided by the `JavascriptExecutor` interface

Using the method, allows you to execute a JavaScript snippet that directly modifies the value of the input field

See skeleton code using Selenium Java below:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.field"));  // replace with your selector / value

// cast the driver to JavascriptExecutor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// remove the 'is-readonly' class using JavaScript
js.executeScript("arguments[0].classList.remove('is-readonly')", inputElement);

// add a new class if required using JavaScript
js.executeScript("arguments[0].classList.add('new-class')", inputElement);

// add a new value/attribute if required using JavaScript
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'Your desired value';", inputElement);
```

**Note:**
*If the webpage re-renders or certain JavaScript events are fired, any changes may be removed*

Comment: Nope it's not working , the shadow root in html page reload form and div , and that can't be done by passing the value. just need copy and paste value. It's chain of method that invoke by the input with focus and select wheel, that chain can be done by copy and paste not change value.Thanks for Helping me <3.